# React Native Paper - Card.Cover source - string vs array with URI field, what option is better?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, react-native, expo

I have a simple `React Native` project which is **working fine**.

**Scenario 1**

Here is a fragment of: `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "react-native": "^0.58.6",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Here is a fragment of code:

```
...
import { ... } from 'react-native';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
...
<Card style={styles.plane} key={i}>
    <Card.Cover source={{ uri: plane.image }} />
    {
        (plane.title || plane.caption || plane.text) &&
        <Card.Content>
            { plane.title && <Title>{i+1}. {plane.title}</Title> }
            { plane.caption && <Caption>{plane.caption}</Caption> }
            { plane.text && <Paragraph>{plane.text}</Paragraph> }
        </Card.Content>
    }
</Card>
...
```

Please, pay attention to: `source={{ uri: plane.image }}`.

**Scenario 2**

Then, I updated the `package.json` file as follows (keeping same version of: `react-native-paper`):

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, in order to make the project work again I have to use the following code:

```
import { ... } from 'react-native';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
...
<Card style={styles.plane} key={i}>
    <Card.Cover source={plane.image} />
    {
        (plane.title || plane.caption || plane.text) &&
        <Card.Content>
            { plane.title && <Title>{i+1}. {plane.title}</Title> }
            { plane.caption && <Caption>{plane.caption}</Caption> }
            { plane.text && <Paragraph>{plane.text}</Paragraph> }
        </Card.Content>
    }
</Card>
```

Please, pay attention to: `source={plane.image}`.

Do you know why after the change on `package.json` I need to modify the value of attribute: `source`?

What version of `package.json` is more recommended? **Scenario 1** or **Scenario 2**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should favour versions in your `package.json` as you have in **Scenario 1**. This lets you easily update to newer versions of `react-native` using the `npm update` command.

The reason you have to change how you pass the `source` is that you are using different versions of react-native in each scenario. Your first scenario uses v0.58 and the second uses a forked version of react-native from `expo`.